# Hibernate Parameter value [568903] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long]

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am using Hibernate 4 and I have a filter in JSF page to get search results. During execution of search I am getting the following exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [568903] did not match 
>       expected type [java.lang.Long]
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.validateParameterBinding(AbstractQueryImpl.java:370)
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.registerParameterBinding(AbstractQueryImpl.java:343)
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:370)
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:323)

Below is my code snippet, how can I fix this issue?

```
private Long projectNo; 

public Long getProjectNo() {
    return projectNo;
}

public void setProjectNo(Long projectNo) {
    this.projectNo = projectNo;
}
```

And in DAO class I have the following

```
String projectNo = filters.get("projectNo");
List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    if (projectNo!= null) {
    ParameterExpression<String> pexp = cb.parameter(String.class, "projectNo");             
    Predicate predicate = cb.equal(emp.get(Project_.projectNo), pexp);
    criteria.add(predicate);
}
TypedQuery<Project> q = entityManager.createQuery(c);
TypedQuery<Long> countquery = entityManager.createQuery(countQ);
q.setParameter("projectNo", projectNo); // error in this line
countquery.setParameter("projectNo", projectNo);
```

**Edit 1**

```
public void getProjects(ProjectQueryData data) {
```

and in `ProjectQueryData` class, I have the following as constructor

```
public ProjectQueryData (int start, int end, String field,
            QuerySortOrder order, Map<String, String> filters) {
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because type of persistent attribute projectNo is `Long`, type argument when creating ParameterExpression should be `Long`. And consequently, because type of the ParameterExpression is `Long`, type of the parameter's value should be Long as well:

```
//because this persistent Attribute is Long:
private Long projectNo; 

//we use Long here as well
ParameterExpression<Long> pexp = cb.parameter(Long.class, "projectNo");
...
//and finally set parameter. Long again, because that is the type 
// type of ParameterExpression:
query.setParameter("projectNo", Long.valueOf(projectNo));
```

Comment: Mikko, Thank you so much, this really has helped to solve the problem. Much appreciated.

Comment: +1 nice job, looks like you were able to piece everything together for a cohesive answer that worked!

Answer (score 3):

`projectNo` is `long` type in DAO, so change it to `long`.

Try this:

```
q.setParameter("projectNo", new Long(projectNo));
```

I think you should change:

```
ParameterExpression<String> pexp = cb.parameter(Long.class, "projectNo");
```

to

```
ParameterExpression<String> pexp = cb.parameter(String.class, "projectNo");
```

Comment: The following error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Named parameter [projectNo] type mismatch; expecting [java.lang.String], found [java.lang.Long]`

Comment: Yout put <code>ParameterExpression<String> pexp = cb.parameter(String.class, "projectNo");</code>

Change this to:

ParameterExpression<String> pexp = cb.parameter(Long.class,
                        "projectNo");

Comment: @PSR Sorry I didn't include that. filter is `Map<String, String> filters = data.getFilters();`

Comment: @PSR I have added that code as Edit 1 in my original question.

Comment: @PSR I have the following method in a class and this class `extends LazyDataModel`    `public List<Project> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
   SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25620/discussion-between-polppan-and-psr)

Comment: @PSR chat [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25620/discussion-between-polppan-and-psr)

Answer (score 3):

In your DAO class, you are getting `projectNo` as a String:

```
String projectNo = filters.get("projectNo");
```

However, in your model class, you are defining `projectNo` as a Long.

When you set parameter in your DAO on this line:

```
q.setParameter("projectNo", projectNo); // error in this line
```

You are setting the parameter as a String.  Try changing that line as follows (assuming that you've null-checked `projectNo`):

```
q.setParameter("projectNo", Long.parseLong(projectNo));
```

It also probably wouldn't hurt (defensive programming) to be sure that `projectNo` is numeric prior to calling `Long.parseLong`.  You can do this with [Apache Commons StringUtils.isNumeric](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html).

Comment: Adding megabytes of Apache libs to your project in order to get one util method isn't defensive, it's actually a bad idea. A simple try/catch works just fine in this case.